# How to partition a 1D list according to specified lengths?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a 1D list `list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and I would like to partition it according to some specified sizes `sizes={2,1,2,4}`, where each element in `sizes` is the number of elements to include in each sublist. The desired result will be `result={{1,2},{3},{4,5},{6,7,8,9}}`. What would be a simple way to do this with list manipulations?

Comment: Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83124/22013), at ``Internal`PartitionRagged``.

Comment: @corey979 this is also now in the ``"System`"`` context as [``TakeList``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html)

Comment: But ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` is usually faster than `TakeList`...

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. This is really a neat function. According to the documentation, it is new in 11.2.